# Kindle App unable to connect

Tags: networking, wine, kindle

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and successfully managed to install the Kindle App v.1.17 via [wine](https://askubuntu.com/a/1155925/1192347), launching it very easily. However, I am greeted with the following message even though I'm connected to the internet:

[image]

In the tools, the network configurations essentially comprise the proxy settings, defaulted to auto-detection.

[image]

Is there anything I can configure to make it run or is this version already phased out? If so, are there any workarounds to use DeDRM with Ubuntu?

Comment: If you are just looking for an e-reader on Ubuntu, there are several.  I would recommend [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/), which can be paired with DeDRM

Comment: I've also had this issue with Ubuntu 20.04. However, with OpenSuse Leap 15.3, the PlayOnLinux installer for the Kindle app was able to connect with my online Amazon account.

Comment: Have you tried selecting "No proxy"?

Answer (score 5):

I can't post a "comment," but this is not an "answer" per se... it's progress toward an answer. I have found a couple other communities that have had the same problem and report that they have solved it by replacing an untrusted certificate. Details here:

https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50471

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=342186&uid=248652

If I were comfortable enough with certificates to talk authoritatively on the topic, I would post instructions. For now all I can do is leave this info in the hands of the more experienced.

[EDIT:]
Ok, I have a procedure that works, but for all I know could leave one susceptible to security issues. It goes:

1: Verify that the file `/etc/ssl/certs/b204d74a.0` is not there

2: Comment in the line `mozilla/VeriSign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G5.crt` in the file `/etc/ca-certificates.conf`

3: Create a file called `/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/VeriSign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G5.crt` that contains this certificate block:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

4: Regenerate the certs using the command `sudo update-ca-certificates`

5: Verify that there's now a file called `/etc/ssl/certs/b204d74a.0` which links to your new cert

This worked for me. KindleForPC version 1.15 running on wine now connects up again.

Comment: even after updating certs, still i cannot see ```/etc/ssl/certs/b204d74a.0``` . I have did all 5 steps mentioned above, Anything else i am missing.?

Comment: Hi 3bu1: Did you see that I answered the question more completely on https://askubuntu.com/questions/1351625/kindle-wont-connect/1352995? See my comment addressed to Frank Aldridge, who had misread "comment in" as "comment out". Perhaps the more explicit step-by-step instructions will elucidate something that was incorrect.

Comment: @3bu1 If you're like me you periodically look at this and then give up, so my response may still be useful: `cd /etc/ssl/certs/; sudo c_rehash`. I don't know why `update-ca-certificates` doesn't always seem to do the rehash, but that's the step that actually creates the `*.0` symlinks. Also, `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` is better than modifying a .conf file as most of the answers suggest

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with PlayOnLinux 4.3.4 with Kindle 1.17.1 .
Solved the issue. Downloaded several books with everything appearing to be working properly.

Used nano in terminal to write (copy) the certificate and do the edits.

Thanks for taking the time to figure out a solution and being willing to share it.  Greatly appreciated.

Luc