# KindleForPC running in WINE 6.0.1 doesn't connect to network

Tags: wine, 21.04

I have installed wine version `6.0.1` on ubuntu `21.04` and am attempting to use KindleForPC version `1.33.62002`

After launching the app via `wine KindleForPC-installer-1.33.62002.exe`, I get the below dialog warning:

```
Unable to connect. 
Please check your network settings and proxy configuration
Network settings can be found under Tools > Options > Network
```

I have the network settings for Kindle set to `auto-detect proxy settings` but nothing works so far.

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=39796 The version tested here mentions zero problems with network access so it must be something specific to your own settings.

Comment: Could you give an example of what settings could be changed or modified to fix the issue? I have also tried with PlayOnLinux with the same result.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. But you should know whether you're using some proxy, VPN or other unusual network settings that require the app settings to be adjusted accordingly. I merely linked the reported tests that, again, have no mentions of network problems.

Comment: wine Kindle NOT connect - no internet: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1351625/kindle-wont-connect/1352995 ----------------------------------------------------------------